# How to change the color of a text inside li and make it override?

Tags: css, html-framework-7

I have a newbie question; I have this code, using framework7.

```
<div class="list-block">
        <ul>
         <li>
 <a href=""  class="external item-content" >
  <div id="div1" class="item-media" style="display:block"  ><img ></div>
                      <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title-row">
                          <div class="item-title" ><></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-subtitle"></div>
                      </div></a></li>
                                             </ul>
      </div>
```

The color of the item-title is blue. I want to make it red, bold and override any previous rule? I can't get it done, the CSS code included in the framework is too complicated for me.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

i just added style="color: #FFFF00;"